# External IP of nodes in cluster of Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ip

If the cluster is upgraded or fails, the 3 working nodes in the cluster are deleted and recreated. At this time, the IP of the node exposed to the outside is changed. To solve this problem, is there a way to keep the IP even if I create a new node?

Comment: You can reserve static IP if you want. However, can you expose deeply your use case, because I'm not sure that your pattern and design is the best one.

Comment: I need to agree with guillaume blaquiere about the importance of the setup you're having.  You should be exposing your workloads with `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` or `Ingress`. You shouldn't worry about the external IP addresss of your node. If this address is required as your workload is connecting to some whitelisted service you should take a look on [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example). Please update your question with the setup you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**You can't assign a static IP to a `GKE` node and expect it to be the same after it was "recreated".**

**In case of a node failure or a node upgrade it will be recreated with a new IP (previous static IP will remain unused).**

You can create a `GKE` node and then promote your `Ephemeral` IP to a `Static` one but after a node failure/upgrade it will be released from a resource (`GKE` node).

Please take a look on more explanation below.

---

I've divided this section on 2 parts:

- Ingress traffic
- Egress traffic

#### Ingress traffic (traffic coming **into** the cluster)

You shouldn't be concerned about the `External` IP changes of your `GKE` nodes as the exposed workload should be using either:

- `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` which creates `L4` LoadBalancer (with it's own IP) pointing on all of your nodes (in case of a node's failure, the traffic will be sent to other one)
- `Ingress` which creates `L7 HTTP/HTTPS` Loadbalancer (with it's own IP) pointing on all of your nodes. (in case of a node's failure, the traffic will be sent to other one)

Documentation about `Services` in `GKE`:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Exposing apps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps)*

There is an option to expose your workload with `Service` of type `NodePort` but it needs to be pointed out that this is still a single point of failure. With a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` the traffic have many paths to take (nodes to choose). With a `NodePort` in case of a node failure, your app/software will be unavailable.

#### Egress traffic (traffic coming **out** of the cluster)

If you are concerned about the traffic that is coming out of the cluster that is destined to some specific whitelisted service (a `DB` in other location for example) you can use `Cloud NAT`:

> #### Cloud NAT overview
>
> Cloud NAT ([network address translation](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)) lets Google Cloud virtual machine (VM) instances without external IP addresses and **private Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters** send outbound packets to the internet and receive any corresponding established inbound response packets.
>
> *[Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: Overview](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview)*

With that approach you can create a [private GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters). Your nodes will only have an internal IP addresses. You can then configure earlier mentioned Cloud NAT so that the nodes will route the packets through a Cloud Router. All of your nodes will be visible in the Internet from the same static IP that will not change in case of any node failure.

Here you have an example setup:

- *[Cloud.google.com: NAT: Docs: GKE example](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example)*

---

From the perspective of node failure and node upgrades, I encourage you to check the official documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Cluster upgrades](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: How to: Upgrading a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster)*

You could also look on:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Regional clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters)*